# Can not start kurento repository server

Tags: java, git, ubuntu, kurento

When I followed the Kurento Tutorials to run the example `Java - Repository`,which needs install the kurento repository server first,I met some problem.

Following the Kurento Repository Server installation guide ,in the last step, I run server at user-level by the commands :

```
 $ cd kurento-repository-server-x.y.z
 $ ./bin/start.sh
```

Unluckily,it shows

```
$ bash ./start.sh
=========================================================================

  Kurento Repository Bootstrap Environment

  KREPO_BINARY: /home/lcrc/kurento-java/kurento-repository/kurento-repository-server/target/kurento-repository-server-6.6.1-SNAPSHOT/lib/kurento-repo.jar

  JAVA: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+TieredCompilation 

  KREPO_OPTS:  -DconfigFilePath=/home/lcrc/kurento-java/kurento-repository/kurento-repository-server/target/kurento-repository-server-6.6.1-SNAPSHOT/config/kurento-repo.conf.json -Dkurento-repo.log.file=/home/lcrc/kurento-java/kurento-repository/kurento-repository-server/target/kurento-repository-server-6.6.1-SNAPSHOT/logs/kurento-repo.log -Dlogging.config=/home/lcrc/kurento-java/kurento-repository/kurento-repository-server/target/kurento-repository-server-6.6.1-SNAPSHOT/config/kurento-repo-log4j.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=/home/lcrc/kurento-java/kurento-repository/kurento-repository-server/target/kurento-repository-server-6.6.1-SNAPSHOT/config/kurento-repo-log4j.properties

=========================================================================

no main manifest attribute, in /home/lcrc/kurento-java/kurento-repository/kurento-repository-server/target/kurento-repository-server-6.6.1-SNAPSHOT/lib/kurento-repo.jar
```

OK,it can not find the class which includes `main` method.

So I changed the last command of the `start.sh` from

```
exec $JAVA $JAVA_OPTS $KREPO_OPTS -jar $KREPO_BINARY
```

to

```
exec $JAVA $JAVA_OPTS $KREPO_OPTS -cp $KREPO_BINARY org.kurento.repository.KurentoRepositoryServerApp
```

I am sure that `org.kurento.repository.KurentoRepositoryServerApp` includes a `main` method after I view the source code.

However, it show another error:

```
$ bash ./start.sh
=========================================================================

  Kurento Repository Bootstrap Environment

  KREPO_BINARY: /home/lcrc/kurento-java/kurento-repository/kurento-repository-server/target/kurento-repository-server-6.6.1-SNAPSHOT/lib/kurento-repo.jar

  JAVA: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+TieredCompilation 

  KREPO_OPTS:  -DconfigFilePath=/home/lcrc/kurento-java/kurento-repository/kurento-repository-server/target/kurento-repository-server-6.6.1-SNAPSHOT/config/kurento-repo.conf.json -Dkurento-repo.log.file=/home/lcrc/kurento-java/kurento-repository/kurento-repository-server/target/kurento-repository-server-6.6.1-SNAPSHOT/logs/kurento-repo.log -Dlogging.config=/home/lcrc/kurento-java/kurento-repository/kurento-repository-server/target/kurento-repository-server-6.6.1-SNAPSHOT/config/kurento-repo-log4j.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=/home/lcrc/kurento-java/kurento-repository/kurento-repository-server/target/kurento-repository-server-6.6.1-SNAPSHOT/config/kurento-repo-log4j.properties

=========================================================================

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Servlet
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2625)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2866)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1676)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Servlet
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 6 more
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure which tag you're working with from the kurento-java repo, but I'm working with current master (`6.6.2-SNAPSHOT`).

There were two things I did to get this to work:

1.) Instead of supplying where to find the main, remove the mainClass reference in the pom.xml file and let the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` do its magic. Go to the plugin section and remove the configuration for `spring-boot-maven-plugin`.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <!-- REMOVE CONFIGURATION BEGIN -->
    <!-- <configuration>
            <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
            <layout>ZIP</layout>
            <classifier>exec</classifier>
    </configuration> -->
    <!-- REMOVE CONFIGURATION END -->
    <executions>
            <execution>
                    <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
            </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

2.) After doing this, there's a logback library collision. So exclude the `spring-boot-starter-logging` that gets included with `spring-boot-starter-web`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
       <!-- ADD EXCLUSION BEGIN -->
       <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
       <!-- ADD EXCLUSION END -->
</dependency>
```

Then, you shouldn't have to alter the `start.sh` script at all.

Comment: THX,I will try it

Comment: Works exactly as described for latest tag (still 6.6.2).